# App fails to build with an error: 2 files found with path 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I tried building my app but it wouldn't build and show this error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins' from inputs:
      - C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1203ed0043761220f2e7b9faa528e635\transformed\jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.31.jar
      - C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a14ecf8d638c881bd231708fc869e941\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.0.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
     for more information
```

I tried

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'internal.kotlin_builtins'
```

but this doesn't work, I have also tried to Invalidate caches and Restart but to no avail.

I am still learning how to code in android studio so I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The correct path should be:

```
 exclude 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins'
```